# Padding of Sliders affect the Fixed Top Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a HTML section of Top Bar which is fixed to view port. And another section of slider. These two 2 section are not totally related to each other as they are the same level in DOM tree. But when I edit the default padding of div.col of Slider, it affect the TopBar. It seems top bar is pulled to bottom and right side when padding of Section edited. I have tried my ways but no way help. Could you please advise any suggestion? Thank you so much. You can view live demo at: https://vanminhquangtri.github.io/football-fashion/

The Top Slide:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import TinySlider from "tiny-slider-react"
const settings = {
    items: 1,
    nav: false,
    autoplay: true
}

const TopSlide = () => {
    return (
        <section className="top-slide">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="wrap">
                            <TinySlider settings={settings}>
                                <div className="slide-item item-1">
                                    <div className="background-image"></div>
                                    <div className="slide-caption">
                                        <h5 className="title">Always update the latest</h5>
                                        <NavLink
                                            to="/best-sales"
                                            className="link"
                                        >
                                            Discover Now
                                        </NavLink>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="slide-item item-2">
                                    <div className="background-image"></div>
                                    <div className="slide-caption">
                                        <h5 className="title">Bring you the champion's fashion</h5>
                                        <NavLink
                                            to="/champion"
                                            className="link"
                                        >
                                            Discover Now
                                        </NavLink>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="slide-item item-3">
                                    <div className="background-image"></div>
                                    <div className="slide-caption">
                                        <h5 className="title">Top-five leagues in the world</h5>
                                        <NavLink
                                            to="/all-fashion"
                                            className="link"
                                        >
                                            Discover Now
                                        </NavLink>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </TinySlider>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default TopSlide;
```

The TopBar:

```
// top bar of web page
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import Logo from "../../Assets/images/section-top-bar/ball.png";
import Leagues from "../../Assets/images/section-top-bar/leagues.jpg";
import HotDeal from "../../Assets/images/section-top-bar/hotdeal.png";

const TopBar = () => {
    return (
        <section className="top-bar">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {/* ball icon */}
                    <div className="col-3 ball-icon">
                        <div className="wrap">
                            <NavLink
                                to="/"
                                exact={true}
                            >
                                <img
                                    src={Logo}
                                    alt="ball-icon"
                                />
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* icons of top-5 leagues */}
                    <div className="col-6 leagues-icon">
                        <div className="wrap">
                            <NavLink
                                to="/most-concerned"
                                exact={true}
                            >
                                <img
                                    src={Leagues}
                                    alt="leagues-icon"
                                />
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* hot deals icon */}
                    <div className="col-3 top-bar-hot-deals">
                        <div className="wrap">
                            <NavLink
                                to="/hot-deal"
                                exact={true}
                            >
                                <img
                                    src={HotDeal}
                                    alt="leagues-icon"
                                />
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default TopBar;
```

CSS:

```
/*--- top bar ---*/
.top-bar {
  z-index: 2000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  background: white;
  .container-fluid {
    .row {
      .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        a {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
        }
        img {
          height: 30px;
        }
      }
      .col-3.ball-icon {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding-left: 5px;
        img {
          width: 30px;
        }
      }
      .col-6.leagues-icon {
        text-align: center;
        img {
          height: 35px;
        }
      }
      .col-3.top-bar-hot-deals {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 5px;
        img {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
/*--- end top bar ---*/
```

Slider:

```
/*--- top slide ---*/
.top-slide {
margin-top: 10px;
  .container-fluid {
    .row {
      .col {
        padding: 0; PROBLEM HERE, IF REMOVE THIS TOP BAR WILL BE NOT AFFECTED, BUT I NEED TO KEEP THIS SO THAT IT LOOKS BETTER IN MOBILE
        .wrap {
          .tns-outer {
            > button {
              display: none;
            }
            position: relative;
            /* next and back button of slide */
            .tns-controls {
              z-index: 100;
              position: absolute;
              top: 40%;
              width: 100%;
              padding: 0 5px;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
              button {
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                background: transparent;
                color: transparent;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background : {
                  size: cover;
                  position: center;
                  repeat: no-repeat;
                }
              }
              button[data-controls=prev] {
                background-image: url("../src/Assets/images/section-top-slide/previous-3.png")
              }
              button[data-controls=next] {
                background-image: url("../src/Assets/images/section-top-slide/next-3.png")
              }
            }
            .tns-ovh {
              .tns-inner {
                .tns-slider {
                  /* each item of slider is a div named slide-item */
                  .slide-item {
                    .background-image {
                      height: 150px;
                      background: {
                        position: center 0;
                        repeat: no-repeat;
                        size: cover;
                      }
                    }
                    .slide-caption {
                      text-align: center;
                      .title {
                        font-weight: bold;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        margin-bottom: 0;
                      }
                      .link {
                        color: white;
                        background: $color-red;
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding: 2px 5px;
                        border-radius: 3px;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  .slide-item.item-1 {
                    .background-image {
                      background-image: url("../src/Assets/images/section-top-slide/tot.webp")
                    }
                  }
                  .slide-item.item-2 {
                    .background-image {
                      background-image: url("../src/Assets/images/section-top-slide/arsenal.jpg")
                    }
                    .title {
                      text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px $color-red;
                    }
                  }
                  .slide-item.item-3 {
                    .background-image {
                      background-image: url("../src/Assets/images/section-top-slide/mc.jpg")
                    }
                    .title {
                      text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #5fa5e3;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
/*--- end top slide ---*/
```

Comment: cant understand your question. where topbar should be?

Comment: Jerry top bax is fixed to the bottom